# Entity Framework - Connect Newly Added Poco Entity And Load Child Objects (Insert/Add)

Tags: entity-framework, orm

I'd like to know whether is it possible for newly created (poco) entity Added to DbContext to be connected (so that child objects can be lazy loaded on navigation)

```
var user = new User();
user.LocationID = 3;
dbContext.Users.Add(user);
var locationName = user.Location.Name;
```

(Note: I understand that I can get the Location object and assign it directly, the example above is just for the purpose of this question)

(Note II: I can create a proxy object and then copy the values, such object would be connected (and do the lazy load) but any complex child objects (other pocos) wouldn't be included in copy)

Is there a way to connect (or load) the Added poco?

Comment: This is quite interesting, im supprised the above doesnt work (given you are lazy loading) Perhaps you need to savechanges first?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor yes once you SaveChanges the object is connected. However I'm trying to work with the object before it is saved.

Comment: This is just speculation but it could be due to validation, if you havent actually committed the row to the DB you dont actually know if the FK exists.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor makes sense but then when using new proxy (instead of poco) in the same scenario the child properties do lazy load (even for new entity)

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that when working with foreign keys and POCOs you can explicitlty lazy load a reference property after setting the FK like so:

```
context.Entry(e).Reference(propName).Load();
```

If you need to traverse the object graph often then it is worth considering if working on the conceptual level and not with foreign key properties is easier for you.

Synchronising of FK and nav properties can occur on DetectChanges() when the entity represented by the navigation property is being tracked by the context. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) suggests that this only occurs when the objects have permanent keys.

> If the reference is in the added state (in this example, the course
>   object), the reference navigation property will not be synchronized
>   with the key values of a new object until SaveChanges is called.
>   Synchronization does not occur because the object context does not
>   contain permanent keys for added objects until they are saved.

However it seems the documentation is incorrect or misleading and synchronisation of nav properties and foreign keys will still occur when working with the properties of a new added entity that is in the `Added` state and without a permanent key.

Below is some test code on my own data model that I used to investigate this. This is using EF5 with .Net4 which I understand is actually EF4.3.

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
  /*
   * Uncomment these lines to test assigning FK Id when entity is being tracked
   */
  Customer cust1 = context.Customers.OrderBy(x => x.Id).First();
  Customer cust2 = context.Customers.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Skip(1).First();

  /*
   * Uncomment these lines to test assigning FK Id 
   * without having entity loaded in ObjectStateManager
   */
  //Customer cust1 = context.Customers.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(x => x.Id).First();
  //Customer cust2 = context.Customers.AsNoTracking()
  //                         .OrderBy(x => x.Id).Skip(1).First();

  //new entities
  Quote proxyQ = context.Quotes.Create();
  Quote pocoQ = new Quote();

  /*
   * if adding the new entities to context before setting FK properties
   * DetectChanges must be called later to attempt sync with nav props
   */
  context.Quotes.Add(proxyQ);
  context.Quotes.Add(pocoQ);

  //set FK Customer ids
  proxyQ.CustomerId = cust1.Id;
  pocoQ.CustomerId = cust2.Id;

  /*
   * FK / nav prop sync happens on DetectChanges() if the Customer 
   * entity is being tracked
   * it must be explicitly called if it has not been called using 
   * one of the AutoDetectChanges functions in order to sync
   */
  context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

  /*
   * Alternatively, if the new entities are added to context after setting FK props
   * and AutoDetectChanges is enabled then DetectChanges is called implicitly and
   * FK / nav prop sync will happen here if the matching Customer entity is 
   * being tracked by the context.
   */
  //context.Quotes.Add(proxyQ); 
  //context.Quotes.Add(pocoQ);

  /*
   * If assigning FK Id and the entity the id represents is not tracked then 
   * proxy will lazy load Customer here.
   */
  Console.WriteLine("Proxy quote with key {0} linked to customer with name {1}",
   proxyQ.Id.ToString(), proxyQ.Customer != null ? proxyQ.Customer.Name : "null");

  /*
   * Obviously no lazy loading of Customer can occur here for a POCO
   */
  Console.WriteLine("POCO quote with key {0} linked to customer with name {1}",
   pocoQ.Id.ToString(), pocoQ.Customer != null ? pocoQ.Customer.Name : "null");

  /*
   * But we can explicit lazy load when using POCO if we have assigned 
   * an FK Customer Id to a POCO quote and the Customer entity is not 
   * being tracked by context
   */
   //context.Entry(pocoQ).Reference("Customer").Load();
   //Console.WriteLine("POCO quote with key {0} linked to customer with name {1}",
   //  pocoQ.Id.ToString(), pocoQ.Customer != null ? pocoQ.Customer.Name : "null");
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, however when you create a new proxy instead (_dbContext.Users.Create<User>()) which also doesn't have permanent key yet, the child objects are lazy loaded... so it doesn't seem to be the issue of the key

Comment: @AndrejKovacik, I did a little experimenting on my data model. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort (+1). I'm actually using .NET 4.5 (EF5) and I'm a bit surprised this would behave differently but DetectChanges doesn't sync the properties for Pocos in my case (I'll have to do more testing to see whether it is a different version or something specific in my code)

Comment: Looking at your code again, I see that [Customer] is loaded into the context (1st line) which then doesn't require Lazy-load so the sync up is only between objects in context. (I think if you remove that line and change the .CustomerId = cust.Id to .CustomerId = 1; the result will be different)

Comment: @AndrejKovacik, you are right. I got carried away testing FK to nav prop synchronising. I have changed my test code a little to make it more applicable to your question. If you do not have the object represented by the FK in memory then you can explicitly lazy load with a POCO like so: `context.Entry(e).Reference(propName).Load();`